# centOS 7 Can't install php-mbstring extension

Tags: php, unix, centos, installation, mbstring

i've tried to install the extension mbstring but i have the following error:

```
    Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
        Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
        Installed: php-common-5.4.38-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.38-1.el7.remi
        Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
        Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
        Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
        Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What could i do to resolve the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 20):

For people who want to know how to solve this :

```
sudo yum remove php-common
```

Then you can:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

It will automaticcaly install dependecies (php-common)

Comment: On linux php version 5.6.x run `sudo yum install php56-mbstring`

Comment: @hyip thanks, I have run `sudo yum install php56-mbstring` command and restart server `sudo service httpd restart` my problem has solved.

Comment: This may lead to a complete uninstall of php and related modules.

Comment: doing this broke my php setup on Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

Comment: Got the same problem, this solution is working just fine. Thanks JakeGould

Comment: Doing this broke my php setup on Amazon EC2, but only after this - it was possible to install all other modules (`yum install php`, `yum install php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64`), etc.

Answer (score 15):

This answer from AWS Amazon forum:

```
yum -y install yum-utils
yum repolist all
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

Then you can install `php-mbstring`, and maybe, I don't know exactly, but maybe it can help for servers on Amazon only.

Comment: Thanks.  The last command ie `yum-config-manager ....` worked for me on AWS RHEL 7.

Comment: Yes, me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

need to search which mbstring version required you.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release && php -v && yum search mbstring



========================================================================= N/S matched: mbstring ==========================================================================
ea-php54-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php55-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php71-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php72-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php73-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
```

now you can check what you actually need like i am using php7.1 so my command will be

```
sudo yum install ea-php71-php-mbstring
```

Comment: It work for me, if you manage server that install php with cpanel, this is the correct answer

Comment: Upvoted initially, because of the elegant search command.
However on my Centos 7.9  system (php 5.6 from remi repo), a normal `yum install php-mbstring` did the trick, while the `yum install php56-php-mbstring` did not.
You can check with `php -m | grep mb` it should return `mbstring`

Answer (score 7):

**The selected answer is liable to change the installed PHP version.** When not using the stock CentOS PHP, `yum` will try to install the `mbstring` extension for the wrong version of PHP.

You can check *your* installed PHP version with `php -v`:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.36 (cli) (built: May 28 2016 12:05:32)
```

Then go ahead and install the correct `mbstring` version for *your* installed PHP version:

```
$ sudo yum install php55w-mbstring
```

Comment: I get the errro `No package php55w-mbstring available.`

Comment: @M-T-A: Post the output of `cat /etc/redhat-release && php -v && yum search mbstring` and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5):

You must specify the same version as your php-common, mine is php70w-common

```
 sudo yum install php70w-mbstring
```

Comment: that was EXACTLY my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Non of above works for godaddy dedicated server centOS 6, apache 2.4, php 5.6

Instead, you should

Install the mbstring PHP Extension with EasyApache

check if you already have it by, putty or ssh

php -m | grep mbstring

[if nothing, means missing mbstring]

Now you need to goto godaddy your account page,

click manager server,

open whm ----- search for apache,

open "easy apache 4"(my case)

Now you need customize currently installed packages,

by

click "customize" button on top line next to "currently installed package..."

search mbstring,

click on/off toggle next to it.

click next, next, .... privision..done.

Now you should have mbstring

by check again at putty(ssh)

php -m | grep mbstring  [should see mbstring]

or you can find mbstring at phpinfo() page

Answer (score 4):

Been searching for the answer for half day, then only realise cPanel / WHM version of CentOS will disable YUM to update php. You shall remove `php*` from exclude list in `/etc/yum.conf`.

....

Answer (score 4):

> Non of above works for godaddy dedicated server centOS 6, apache 2.4, php 5.6

Instead, you should install the mbstring PHP Extension with EasyApache check if you already have it by, putty or ssh

```
php -m | grep mbstring       [if nothing, means missing mbstring]
```

Now you need to go to godaddy your account page,

```
1.click manager server,

2.open whm ----- search for apache,

3.open "easy apache 4"(my case)
```

Now you need customize currently installed packages,by

```
4.click "customize" button on top line next to "currently installed package..."

5.In the search bar write "mbstring",

6.click on/off toggle next to it.

7.click next, next, .... privision..done.
```

Now you should have mbstring by check again at putty(ssh)

```
php -m | grep mbstring         [should see mbstring]
```

or you can find mbstring at phpinfo() page

Thanks, my problem is done

Answer (score 4):

Fedora 28 (Cloud Edition)

`sudo yum install php56-php-mbstring`
`sudo yum install php70-php-mbstring`
`sudo yum install php71-php-mbstring`
`sudo yum install php72-php-mbstring`
`sudo yum install php73-php-mbstring`

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 running PHP 7.4

```
sudo yum install php74-php-mbstring
```